# Server Rack for Home Use?

Tags: rack

I was looking into getting a few shiny rack servers for my home based business.  During this, I realized I would need a server rack (so that it looks neat and tidy at the least).  The only problem?  Even small 15U racks start at $500, and that's just for the crappy ones!

For the price of a small rack, I could buy an extra server!

Any ideas for small office/home office racks?

Comment: I don't care what the currency is, you can't buy a real server for $500.

Comment: @JohnGardeniers The local recycler always has used rack/cabinets for ~$100. They're usually older and not in the best conditions, missing a part or two... but they're dirt cheap and entirely acceptable for a home rack.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you don't want to spend all that money into a rack, buy tower servers instead.

But if you're still wanting to get a cheap rack, [this is a 40USD one](http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/00104291).

Ikea tables have been used for some time in hackerspaces for cheap replacements. More informations on [eth0 hackerspace wiki](http://wiki.eth-0.nl/index.php/LackRack).

Here is the "enterprise" edition from revspace, a dutch hackerspace :

[image]

(notice the [club mate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Club-Mate) bottle)

Edit: 
Here is a side picture of my home lab rack. See [my answer](https://serverfault.com/a/348669/46213) for more pros and cons about it.

[image: industrial_shelves]

Comment: ah, the LackRack setup. Interesting idea.

Comment: IKEA Lack serie, right? :-)

Comment: @3molo: indeed, hence the name `LackRack` ;)

Answer (score 6):

> For the price of a small rack, I could buy an extra server!

But a more mordern machine. My small servers cost around 2000 USD - that is 16gb memory, desktop chip, 8 disks.

> The only problem? Even small 15U racks start at $500,

Try looking at the prices for office furniture ;) THEN you get shocks.

Seriously, 1000 USD for a rack is not a lot of money. Things do not come for free in our society.

Comment: Couldn't agree more, this is serverfault.com, it's not homecheaponetworking.com, this site is for professionals, who usually have budgets for the right tools.

Comment: Thabnks. I thought it may sound harsh.. The poster always can put up a 20 USD cheap rack from wallmart ;)

Comment: Harsh? from you? ;)

Answer (score 1):

I know little about US rack manufacturers, but at least here overseas (Europe), we have a couple of manufacturers serving the "low end" segment. You also always could buy an [open frame](http://www.starcase.com/open_frame_racks.htm) (the LackRack would also fall under this definition) if you do not need the physical access restrictions of a cabinet - they are significantly cheaper than the rack cabinet models.

Answer (score 1):

For my servers I went to one of my local stores and purchased some of the wire shelving units similar to the following:
http://www.metro.com/commercial/shelving/wire/

They are perfect if you are looking to hold a variety of case sizes.  Most of my network cables are neatly velcro wrapped to the vertical poles.  I've been using this for the last 4 years and it's been a great investment for my computer lab at home.

Currently in my rack
(2) UPSs
(2) PDUs
(1) Netscreen SSG20
(1) Raritan KSX-II
(2) Mini Tower systems
(1) 8 Port procurve (zip tied to hang from one of the racks)
(2) Shuttle KPCs

If I want to I can probably add two more Shuttles if I shift the racks around, and if I used the top shelf I could add two or three more mini towers.  The rack I have it about 16"x24".